# 'DueDate' and 'DateOfAward' fields not available in "Send an Email" action

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm building a recurring Power Automate.

The **DateOfAward** and **DueDate** columns are available to me at `Get items`. However in the `Apply to each` --> `Send an eamail (V2)`, I can see every column except the **DateOfAward** and **DueDate**?

I would like these two fields to be in the body of the email along with others (that I can see).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have selected a specific View for missing fields in **Limit columns by View**:

[image]

If not, please save the flow, then re-open it to compare the result.

Comment: No, this did not solve the problem. Made the change you recommended and closed, freshed, reopened. I can still ONLY see the 'DueDate' and 'DateOfCQ' columns as options in the middle, at Apply to each 'Condition'. But when I get to the Send an Email (V2) body, I am not able to see the 'DueDate' or 'DateofCQ' fields as option. for the Send an Email (V2) message body.

Comment: Create a new flow with this list to check if the issue still exists.